# Would the following image be allowed?

Tags: support, logo

In the guidelines for using the SE logos, it says:

> **Do not** distort or alter our logo in any way

Does the following logo do that?

[image: "Actionstack" logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're good, that isn't meaningfully derivative of one of our trademarks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not.  I can't clearly tell that that's the SO logo.  It just looks like an "A" that went through a shredder crooked